# Why need I denote the type for partial applied function on the known type parameter?

Tags: scala

Given the

```
def sum(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b

val add7 = sum(7, _) 
// compiler complains missing $x1's type for $x1 => sum(7, $x1)

val add8 = sum(8, _: Int) 
// fine
```

And curried `sum` can do this without type declaration .

```
def sum_curry(a: Int)(b: Int) = a + b

val add9 = sum_curry(9)(_)
// fine
```

But it's not a generic function, what sum's parameter types can be known and it is already there.

Why cannot Scala know the $x1's type from `b: Int` in `sum`'s signature?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler needs to know the data types of function arguments to map a function call to exactly one function definition (out of many overloaded function definition of with same name)

It will become ambiguous if we try a reverse mapping from function definition to function call to determine the type of a parameter in function call.

Comment: Why does it become ambiguous when I reverse mapping from function definition when only it exists?

Comment: What you are asking is a special case where only one function with the same name occurs. Compilers are generally built to handle all possible cases (including overloaded functions).  One logic which applies to all cases. What you are asking is possible but not generally implemented due to its design complexity. (One logic for every special case).

Answer (score 0):

**Eta expression** can convert this to a value type `(Int, Int) => Int` only when:

- `_` as in place of the argument of list

  val f = sum _
- or, you just omit the argument list.

  val f :(Int, Int) => Int = sum

and specify its type.

- or use each `_`

  val f = sum(_ , _)

As you can see, `sum(7, _)` cannot satisfy any of above.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried the `sum _`. And I am surprise scala can handle two unknown type but why does it cannot handle the case which is given one. It looks like Scala need programmer denote the all types(f:(Int, Int) => Int) ) or left all underscores ( sum _ and sum(_,_) )?

Comment: There are some notes in **Scala Language Reference** (http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf). It show the (1) `sum _` is  the `method value` (2) and `sum(_,_)` is the `Syntax for Anonymous Functions`